# Facebook Scores API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

Can we use Facebook scores API where least score is the best score. e.g. higher times in solving a puzzle are not "better" times, these stories are contextually incorrect when they compare user's scores. Is there any solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply change the approach - in fact *less time* spent on something is better, so user should get *more points*. So, if you have a time limit in your game you can set points for a user as **maxTime - actualTime**.

I used this approach when I created a quiz game with 10 seconds to answer each question and it was perfect for this situation and I think it would fit your game, too.

Comment: Yes, you are right. but its a requirement.. i cant change it.

Comment: Can we use facebook objects to implement this?

Comment: @Avinash can you quote this requirement? Are you sure you have to set points to the value of time the user spent on the task? When I was developing my game I've checked some games, like SongPop, and there was always the same rule - less time = more points.